# Move Divs Randomy JS

Tags: javascript

I should dynamically create 10divs and move them randomly. I have created the divs and I can see them in console but not on screen. Only one div is visible. Maybe I have missed CSS property?

Please help.

Thank you!

```js
create.addEventListener('click' , () => {
    let divs = document.createElement("div")
    let ParentDiv = document.getElementById("parent")
    let w = innerWidth
    let h = innerHeight
    divs.style = `
    width:50px; height:50px; background:red; border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute`
    for(let i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
        console.log(divs)
        ParentDiv.append(divs)
    }
    let RandomPlace = setInterval( () =>{
        let innwidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * w)
        let innheight = Math.floor(Math.random() * h)
        divs.style.top = innwidth + "px"
        divs.style.left = innheight + "px"
    },1000)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #parent{
            width:100%;
            height: 700px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: rgb(122, 119, 119);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="create">Create</button>
    <div id="parent"></div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You use "position: absolute" so i guess all your divs are stacked on top of each other. try position relative

Comment: Nop. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your divs variable actually contains only one div. So your printing the same div 10 times in your for loop.

Reading your code, you should be able to see only 1 div, the parent. 1. You have to create the 10 divs and not just one.

You could do:

```
let divs = [];
for (let i = 0; 1 <= 10; i++) {
  divs.push(document.createElement('div'));
}
```

And then you would also have to append them. For example:

```
for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  ParentDiv.appendChild(divs[i]);
}
```

This should work if you modify this code according to your needs.